# Changing read only file system to read write file system

Tags: permissions, mount, partition

I have switched to Parrot OS as Windows doesn't meet my requirements like tools, good CLI support etc. But to practice hacking (ethical), when I downloaded a machine from vulnhub and tried to install it on Virtualbox, it shows error with no enough storage.

I have enough space in my windows but the problem is the system, that's `/media/user/Windows` in my case. But when I tried to create a VM in `/media/user/Windows`, it shows `NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG`,that simply means unable to write (due to certain reasons).

After running the command `sudo mount -o rw,remount "/media/user/Windows"`, it shows the same error.

In simple words, **I want to know that how can I convert read only file system to read write file system so that I can create file and manage files.**

Comment: It was successful, means no error and also no output. When I right clicked on the folder, it shows create document but throws error on clicking it that no file exists with <default_name>. (it doesn't shows by default)

Comment: Is `re,remount` a typo? Shouldn't it be `rw,remount`?

Comment: I think they are mounted as I can read those files. Also I can copy them to linux system (on dual boot)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if VirtualBox generally forbids users to create a virtual machine on NTFS filesystems. Or you can't write to the partition at all? Try `ntfsfix` on that partition.

Comment: I would look for more information in the kernel message buffer (`dmesg` command, or in case Parrot uses systemd, `journalctl -k`). One problem I have run into several times: You may have hibernated Windows rather than shut it down. The NTFS driver refuses writing to a hibernated filesystem as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use files of windows in parrot but not create new file in the windows partition . you can not write files in windows from linux ,You need to repartition your linux.

According to me ,it might be wrong .

Comment: This is incorrect. Linux can write to NTFS filesystems. From the [NTFS driver's manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g): "ntfs-3g is an NTFS driver, which can **create, remove, rename, move** files, directories, hard links, and streams".